# sortBy visitors with fixed date

Tags: laravel, count, relationship, ranking

I have that code

```
$post = Post::withCount('Visitors', 'Visitors')->orderBy('Visitors_count', 'desc')->get();
```

It works of course but I want to check Visitors from the lastest 2 week for example. So other records should be ignore. How I can do that?

Comment: use created_at column and Carbon date time to get record from last two weeks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count visitors for the last two weeks only:

```
Post::withCount(['Visitors' => function($q) {
    $q->where('created_at', '>', now()->subWeeks(2));
}])->orderBy('Visitors_count', 'desc')->get();
```